# Citizenship UK from permanent residenship

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, citizenship, naturalization

I just received my UK permanent residence  as EU for the period from Nov 2010 to Dec 2015. Now to apply for UK citizenship I know you need to have the permanent residence for at least 1 year. Is that year calculated from the moment you receive the card or from when you have been granted permanent residentship? 
I will explain in another way:
The actual permanent residence card starts from November 2018 (the month the card has been issued) because I just applied for that (again for 5 year 2010-2015).
However in the attached document states I have been granted residentship from Dec 2015.

Which one counts to calculate 12 months of  permanent residence status?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Why are you applying for a permanent residence for the years 2010-2015? It's 2018 now.

Comment: Based on what @phoog has said on [Expatriates.se], I believe you need the document, so 1 year from now, you can apply for citizenship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your papers closely, you will see tha you have permanent residence starting from December 2015, not from the day your received the documents. So you could have applied for citizenship in December 2016, and you can definitely do so now (unless you left the UK for two years, or committed some serious crime, plus you need to be in the UK when you apply).